# Как настроить редирект на https?

Tags: yii2, .htaccess, redirect

У меня есть проект на PHP (yii2). Была задача сделать редирект с http на https для всех страниц. Я добавил в файл .htaccess в корне проекта следующие строки:

```
RewriteEngine on

# redirect to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# redirect the main page to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Теперь редирект работает для всех страниц, за исключением файлов. Т.е. есть файлы, которые лежат на сервере и доступ к ним можно получить так (пример):

mysite.ru/files/file.pdf

mysite.ru/files/pdf/file1.pdf

mysite.ru/files/pdf/file2.pdf

...

По этим ссылкам редиректа не происходит. ChatGPT подсказал добавить правило:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^files/ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

но оно не работает. По https при этом перейти ко всем файлам могу.

Как решить проблему?